# How do I store a value from a sql query into a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$resourcesbuilt = mysql_query("SELECT resourcesbuilt FROM user WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1");

if ($resourcesbuilt<=0 )
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO resources (username, dollars) VALUES ( '$username', '1000')") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_query("UPDATE user SET resourcesbuilt = '1' WHERE username = '$username'");
}
```

Basically I have a column in a user table that acts as a flag that tells me whether a different table has been made for that particular user. Its 0 if it hasn't, and 1 if it has. However it seems I can't just store the query into a variable and check if its 0 or not, because the actual value from the query isn't stored in the var. When I echo the var it just says Resource id #3. My research into php and SQL has failed me. Does anyone know of a way to store the result form a sql query into a variable in php? Or can at least point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the result returned by mysql_query is not usable in this way.  Instead, you have to call

```
$value = mysql_fetch_array($resourcesbuilt, MYSQL_ASSOC)
$value ["resourcesbuilt"]
```

This will give you the value of that field in the table.
Look [here](http://au.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ rs = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET resourcesbuilt = '1' WHERE username = '$username'");
```

will store the result into a recordset named rs
you can retrieve the values then by calling

```
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($rs)
```

will put the whole row into an array named myrow
and retrieve their values by `$myrow[column_name]`

oh and another note
as far as i remember you cannot store them since they are not select statements
the only resource that you'll have is mysql_num_rows