# I need to temporarily "store" info, or put a query in a query and do an insert into SQL Server 2005

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

So I have 2 tables that I need to insert similar data into. They are employee DBs that different applications access. They are:

- dbo_Employees
- dbo_EmpDefaultSchedules
- dbo_EmpUsers
- dbo_EmpDefaultLocation

So on `dbo_Employees`, when you insert a row, the primary key is auto-created. That column is called `EmpID`. There are a total of around 22 different columns being added to these different tables. They are things like `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Address`, `Phone`, etc., etc.

I'm trying to create a script where I can take a list of variables, enter them in once, and run that script to add it to the 4 tables at once (eventually a web page that HR will enter the info and create it themselves)

The only one that is giving me trouble is `dbo_EmpDefaultSchedules`. This is because I need the primary key from `dbo_Employees` (`EmpID`) to insert into `dbo_EmpDefaultSchedules`, and obviously it's not created until the first part of the script runs. My insert statement for the second part is this:

```
INSERT INTO [Database].[dbo].[EmpDefaultSchedules] (StaffCode, EmpID, LastName, FirstName, Dept, MgrStaffCode, IsMgr, PayrollStatus, PayFrequency, StdHrsWk, EmailAddress )
VALUES (@StaffCode, (select EmpID from [Database].[dbo].[Employees] WHERE StaffCode = @StaffCode), @LastName, @FirstName, @Dept, @MgrStaffCode, @IsMgr, @PayrollStatus, @PayrollFrequency, @StdHrsWk, @EmailAddress)
```

When I do this I get this error:

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions
>   are allowed.

I have seen/read this:
[Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641068/subqueries-are-not-allowed-in-this-context-only-scalar-expressions-are-allowed)

And this:
[MYSQL inserting into multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269054/mysql-inserting-into-multiple-tables)

And this:
[How do I store a value from a sql query into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861712/how-do-i-store-a-value-from-a-sql-query-into-a-variable)

And this:
[How do I combine a SELECT + WHERE query with an INSERT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736506/how-do-i-combine-a-select-where-query-with-an-insert-query)

But still cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You retrieve the identity to a variable using SCOPE_IDENTITY just after you insert into employees

[SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: My apologies, I'm really new to SQL and the example in the link does not really make much sense to me. I'm not sure what it's returning. So does SCOPE_IDENTITY store the value for last ROW created (all fields)? If so, how would I specify the field I wanted to insert in the next table?

Comment: It only returns the value created by the identity column.  I assumed EmpID was an Indentity column since you said it was auto generated.

Comment: Can it be _made_ an identity column after the fact? Without changing it's name?

Comment: What is that EmpID now?  Have you even tried to retrieve SCOPE_IDENTITY() as shown in that link?

Comment: If I run: USE [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Employees]
GO
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY] it comes back as NULL

Comment: As shown in the link.  You run that statement AFTER the insert.  Show some effort.  That link is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following.

```
insert into Employees values (x,y,z)
insert into EmpDefaultSchedules (@staffcode, @@identity,....)
```

The @@identity is filled with the inserted EmpID, which you can use later on. If you insert another record after the Employees, and before the EmpDefaultschedules, make sure you put the @@identity in a variable

```
declare @EmpId int
insert into Employees values (x,y,z)
set @EmpId = @@identity
insert into EmpDefaultSchedules (@staffcode, @EmpId,....)
```

Comment: But how does SQL know that @@identity is EmpID? Because I am not inserting EmpID to start. It is an Auto-created PK. I am already using "declare" and "set" for all the values (except **EmpID**). The first part of the script inserts values into **Employee** the EmpID is auto-created. Then I need to insert said employee ID into **EmpDefaultSchedules** so I need to pull that from **Employee**.

Comment: No, that is just the point here. When you insert a record which has a an identity column with it, in this case the EmpID, it will store the inserted identity into the @@identity variable. This is an internal variable..

Comment: It is dangerous to use @@indentity as it gets the last table so if there was a trigger with an identiry it would get a value from a table other than Employee.

Comment: Ofcourse it is dangerous, but it is less performance consuming then to query it.

Comment: Ran some tests and set @EmpId = @@identity was about 0.13 seconds and  SCOPE_IDENTITY was about 0.16.  I am not going to chance a wrong answer on 0.03 seconds.   Someone could create a trigger in the future.

Comment: I depends on how many times you have ran the test. Only 1 time wont do the trick. Try 1000's of times, in a loop for example. Try to look at CPU usage in stead of seconds. That would give a better view. And i am NOT saying you HAVE to use the @@identity, but it is faster, period.

Comment: Why would I look at CPU for 1000 inserts when the question is about a single insert?  OK you feel it is worth risking incorrect information to save less the 1/10 second.  I don't.  Truce?   I did not know you could get @@identity without a select.  That is slick.